# Any galois covering of $P^{1}$ over rationals are of the form $\mathbb{P}^1_L\to\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, galois-theory

I recently came across the following statement,

The Galois coverings of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$ are all of the form
$$\mathbb{P}^1_L\to\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$$ where $L$ is a number field.

How to prove this ,

Any reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a smooth curve over a field $K$. Then there is an exact sequence of etale fundamental groups:

$$1\rightarrow\pi_1(X_{\overline{K}})\rightarrow\pi_1(X)\rightarrow\pi_1(Spec\;K)\rightarrow 1$$

Taking $X= \mathbb{P}^1_K$, we find that $X_{\overline{K}}$ has trivial etale fundamental group (if $K$ is a number field, this follows from the Riemann existence theorem, and the fact that $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the Riemann sphere, which is simply connected).

Thus, the natural map $\pi_1(X)\rightarrow\pi_1(Spec\; K)$ is an isomorphism. If you think about the Galois correspondence, then you'll find that this means precisely that every cover of $X$ comes from pulling back a cover of Spec $K$.

If you're interested in questions like this, I would really recommend that you learn about Galois categories. There are lots of books/articles on this. For example, Lenstra's *Galois Theory for Schemes* is very readable and is available online:

http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf